# Ag-grid export meta-data values

Tags: angular, export-to-csv, ag-grid

I currently have functionality to export my ag-grid to csv. The problem is, the UI is meant to not show any values in the grid (only color the cell red or green).

Is there a way to export some meta-data (by hiding a value behind the cell) so that when the .csv is generated, the background-colors are converted to PASS (green) and FAIL (red)?

**Existing Code:**

```
this.subscription = this.messageService.clickEventEmitter.subscribe(message => {
     this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv({
         skipHeader: false,
         skipFooters: true,
         skipGroups: true,
         fileName:'myFile.csv'}),
     });
});
```

**Grid Contents:**

[image: Grid Contents]

Comment: the grid gets data, what this data looks like?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I'm choosing to take the data and convert it to a background-color, I'm not displaying any of the data that led to the color. The data looks like 1 for pass, 0 for fail

Comment: exporting the styles from the ag-grid is an enterprise feature - Excel Export and not the CSV export.

Comment: Are you using a [cellRenderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/)? or are you preprocessing your data before passing it to ag-grid?

Comment: @JarodMoser I do have a cellRenderer but it's for unrelated data that is occasionally shown in the cells. 99% of the time the cell will be blank. I'm wondering if there's a way to store the 0/1 value in the cell for export use later. (I'm using the 0/1 value in a cellStype: to set the background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the easiest solution is to use the [`processCellCallback`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#processcellcallback) parameter of the `exportToCSV` function. Something like this:

```
processCellCallback: cell => cell.backgroundColor == 'green' ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'
```

However, It sounds like you are preprocessing the data somehow. I would suggest you pass the raw data to the ag-grid, then use the cellRenderer to display a green or red background. This way, the `exportToCSV` function recieves the raw data as well and you might not need a processCellCallback.

Comment: very helpful, I need to keep the grid clear of 0/1s (raw data) is that possible even if I send the raw data to the grid?

Comment: of course, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8XPuz8o14go4DWU0lXiV?p=preview) is a simple example. I think the only "trick" that might not be self explanatory is setting the '&nbsp' as the innerHTML so that the div displays